# Micro MODULE_NOT_FOUND after updating to nextjs 11

Tags: node.js, next.js, apollo, apollo-server

I updated my nextjs install and apollo,

> Error: Cannot find module 'micro' Require stack:
>
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\apollo-server-micro\dist\ApolloServer.js
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\apollo-server-micro\dist\index.js
> - C:\work\cloud.next\server\pages\api\auth.js
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
> - C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
>   at Function.mod._resolveFilename (C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:4:1855)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
>   at Object. (C:\work\cloud\node_modules\apollo-server-micro\dist\ApolloServer.js:5:17)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\apollo-server-micro\dist\ApolloServer.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\apollo-server-micro\dist\index.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\.next\server\pages\api\auth.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js',
>   'C:\work\cloud\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next'   ] }

I'm not surewhat's missing as this was working before the package update - reading up on online docs there doesn't seemt o have been any changes made to how apollo server micro works?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and solved it with a simple [`yarn add micro`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-micro).

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by running `npm i micro` then restarting the server, worked fine after that